# Not able to get cookie in different context

Tags: java, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

i am setting cookie in context A and trying to get in context B in same domain . I am writing this code ....

```
Cookie cook= new Cookie("Name","value");
cook.setPath("/");
cook.setDomain(".foo.com");
response.addCookie(cook);
```

what is wrong here ? This is how i am getting the cookie in another context ..please note that my code is working fine in same context

```
Cookie cookie = null;
Cookie[] cookies = null;
cookies = request.getCookies();
       out.println(cookies);
      for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++){

                  cookie = cookies[i];
                  if("Name".equals(cookie.getName( ))){
                  out.println("Name : " + cookie.getName( ) + ",  ");
                  out.println("Value: " + cookie.getValue( )+" <br/>");
         }}
```

Comment: show us how are you trying to get the cookie? and when you are trying to get what error or issue you got?

Comment: No error ..it is just not displaying the values....i think i am getting the cookie fine..i have update the quetion how i am getting the cookie....please see

Answer (score -1):

Try to give the cookie a lifetime.

```
cookie.setMaxAge(86400) // 24h
```

A cookie without lifetime is bound to the browsing session. You might be in a different session when browsing in a different context.

Comment: tried this ..it did not work..not sure where i am wrong in this.

Comment: Are you sure both request share the same domain? Specially when testing locally the domains sometimes get messed up. Can you compare

    `request.getRequestURL()`

and 

    `request.getServerName()`

Comment: i have compared these values ... serverName is same in both context and URL in context A is same where i am setting cookies but in context B i am getting request.getRequestURL() value as null...also context B is a JSR portlet.. any idea why i am getting null value there ?